# How to change components upon search in React tool kit?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am currently building an application that allows users to search for movies and tv shows. When the user enters a search query, I have a component that displays cards for each film. The user can then click on one of the cards to bring them to another component that displays the details of that selected film. The problem I have run into is that when the user is on this details component and they enter another search query (the search bar is in the header)the display does not switch back to the movie listings component and stays on the details page. I know the API and search bar are working correctly btw. What I am trying to accomplish is when the user enters a search while on the details component, the component that displays the movie cards is presented again. This is my first project using React so I am kind of lost right now and any help would be appreciated.

This is some of my current code:

- Slice:

```
export const fetchAsyncMovies = createAsyncThunk('movies/fetchAsyncMovies', async (term) => {
    const response = await movieApi.get(`?apiKey=${APIKey}&s=${term}&type=movie`)
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    if(response.data.Error){
        alert(response.data.Error);
        return window.location.replace('/');
    }
    return response.data;
});

export const fetchAsyncShows = createAsyncThunk('movies/fetchAsyncShows', async (term) => {
    const response = await movieApi.get(`?apiKey=${APIKey}&s=${term}&type=series`)
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    return response.data;
});

export const fetchAsyncDetail = createAsyncThunk('movies/fetchAsyncDetail', async (id) => {
    const response = await movieApi.get(`?apiKey=${APIKey}&i=${id}&plot=full`)
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    if(response.data.Error){
        alert(response.data.Error);
        return window.location.replace('/');
    }
    return response.data;
});

const initialState = {
    movies: {},
    shows: {},
    selectedMovieOrShow: {},
};

const moviesSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'movies',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        removeSelectedMovieOrShow: (state) => {
            state.selectedMovieOrShow = {};
        },
        removeMoviesAndShows: (state) => {
            state.movies = {};
            state.shows = {};
        },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchAsyncMovies.pending, () => {
            return console.log('Pending');
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchAsyncMovies.fulfilled, (state, {payload}) => {
            console.log('Fetched');
            return {...state, movies: payload };
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchAsyncMovies.rejected, () => {
            return console.log('Rejected');
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchAsyncShows.fulfilled, (state, {payload}) => {
            console.log('Fetched');
            return {...state, shows: payload };
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchAsyncDetail.fulfilled, (state, {payload}) => {
            console.log('Fetched');
            return {...state, selectedMovieOrShow: payload };
        });
    }
})

export const { removeSelectedMovieOrShow } = moviesSlice.actions;
export const { removeMoviesAndShows } = moviesSlice.actions;
export const getAllMovies = (state) => state.movies.movies;
export const getAllShows = (state) => state.movies.shows;
export const getSelectedMovieOrShow = (state) => state.movies.selectedMovieOrShow;
export default moviesSlice.reducer;
```

- Header component:

```
const Header = () => {
    const [term, setTerm] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!term || term === ''){
            alert('Please enter a valid search query!');
            return;
        }
        dispatch(removeMoviesAndShows());
        dispatch(fetchAsyncMovies(term));
        dispatch(fetchAsyncShows(term));
        setTerm('');
    }
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <Link to='/'>
            <div className='logo'>Film Finder <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></div>
            </Link>
            <div className='search-bar'>
                <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                    <input type='text' value={term} placeholder='Search Movies or Shows' onChange={(e) => setTerm(e.target.value)} />
                    <button type='submit'><i className='fa fa-search'></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className='user-image'>
                <img src={user} alt='user' />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

- App component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header></Header>
        <div className='container'>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/movie/:imdbID' element={<MovieDetail />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting that any time the search input value is changing for the app to navigate back to `"/"`? Or something else? Can you [edit] to clarify the use case and what exactly the issue is you are having?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).